# What is a good rule of thumb for setting memory limits on KDB rdbs?

Tags: kdb

The question basically says it all.

How much memory should we allocate on an RDB. Is it 50% above the expected traffic or more like 3x of the expected traffic?

I cannot find any suggestions on the KX website.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the data in your HDB (uncompressed) would determine how much memory your RDB needs, and would determine whether or not you need to implement intraday writedowns (e.g. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/w-q/). And/or similarly, the size of the data in your tickerplant log also determines how much memory your RDB needs.

One approach is to get a daily estimate of uncompressed size and take the max day. Then it would be up to you to decide how much more then the max day you're willing to allocate (and your available machine resources would set the upper bound).

To determine the memory footprint:

- using HDB - use either `-21!` and/or `-22!` on your historical data in one date slice
- using tickerplant log - replay a full log into memory and observe `.Q.w[]`

Comment: This is good, but I think also needs to include an allocation for the largest joins into a temporary variable.

Comment: how would you check for the largest joins ? 
Should I just look at all queries issued against the RDB and check the joins manually or is there a better way? 

also @terrylynch, do you know if there are any suggestions from KX in terms of the multiple used for memory allocation? feels very subjective to just go 2x on our max historical needs.

Comment: They used to have RAM recommendations many years ago but they don't offer any now.  Back in 2004 they recommended RAM to be 4*daily but that meant RAM for the entire machine, not just for the RDB. Presumably back then the 4*daily RAM would have been shared across RDB and HDB. See: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/d/src/tick.txt#L15